# Calling methods from classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing some classes:

```
bean_version = "1.0"
from random import randint
console = []
print "Running Bean v%s" % bean_version
#Math Function
class math(object):
    def __init__(self, op1 = 0, op2 = 0):
        self.op1 = op1
        self.op2 = op2
    def add(self):
        return self.op1 + self.op2
    def sub(self):
        return self.op1 - self.op2
    def mul(self):
        return self.op1 * self.op2
    def div(self):
        return self.op1 / self.op2
```

What I realized I could do is:

```
math.add(math(3,5))
==>8
```

What I'm wondering is, is there any way to be able to do:

```
math.add(3,5)
```

Python 2.7.10

Comment: First you need to instantiate your class like `m = math(3,4)` and then access its methods.

Comment: Actually, `math(3,5).add()` is currently how to use what you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible. In this case you use the class just as a way to logically group your operators (add, sub, mul, div) and you don't really need to initialize the operands in the class instance itself. This calls for the [`staticmethods`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator, and the code looks like the one below.
You can also see it in action here: https://eval.in/639864

```
bean_version = "1.0"
from random import randint
console = []
print "Running Bean v%s" % bean_version
#Math Function
class math(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def add(op1, op2):
        return op1 + op2
    @staticmethod
    def sub(op1, op2):
        return op1 - op2
    @staticmethod
    def mul(op1, op2):
        return op1 * op2
    @staticmethod
    def div(op1, op2):
        return op1 / op2

print math.add(3,5)
print math.sub(3,5)
print math.mul(3,5)
print math.div(3,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. The problem currently is that you are defining your class such that the operands must be passed to the *constructor*, not the operators. Try this:

```
class math(object):
    def add(self, op1=0, op2=0):
        return op1 + op2
    def sub(self, op1=0, op2=0):
        return op1 - op2
    def mul(self, op1=0, op2=0):
        return op1 * op2
    def div(self, op1=0, op2=0):
        return op1 / op2
m = math()
m.add(2, 3)
```

Given that none of the methods use `self`, they should actually be static methods. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: Your link is to static methods, but you aren't using any?

Comment: Static methods aren't required to get the code working so I mentioned them only as a footnote. Given the OP seems to be new to classes, I didn't want to include them as part of my solution because then they would have to also learn how and when to use static methods.

Comment: @Curtis Lusmore could I still add default variables, or would I not need to?

Comment: Sorry, yes of course. I've updated my answer to include the optional parameters.

Comment: I figured out you actually don't need the self variable or the default ones anyway.